# Postgres Logical Replication - Limiting Bandwidth Per Publisher/Subscriber

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I have one publisher with around 50 subscribers. Not so often (few times a month) a binary file of size 30MB is written to the database.  At this point all subscriber are getting this file and I have network bandwidth issues.

1. Is it possible to limit (in Postgres or OS) the bandwidth used by the logical replication per publisher/subscribers?
2. Is it possible to limit the bandwidth used during first sync?

Answer (score 0):

At the PostgreSQL level I can suggest trying to reduce `max_wal_senders` parameter at the sending server (it is 10 by default)
Depending on the latency you can accept, you can limit the number of concurrent sending processes up to 1 process at a time